# How to set javax.xml.transform.TransformerFactory system property

Tags: java, xslt-1.0, xsl-fo, xalan

I am using `javax.xml.transform.Transform` to convert an XML file to a PDF. This works fine on its own, but some part of the project is using Xalan, which implements its own `TransformerFactory`, and something in there doesn't work with Cyrillic.

I have found at https://xml.apache.org/xalan-j/usagepatterns.html that there is a property which is used to define the used factory :

> TransformerFactory is an abstract class with a static newInstance() method that instantiates the concrete subclass designated by the javax.xml.transform.TransformerFactory system property.
>
> The default setting for this system property is org.apache.xalan.processor.TransformerFactoryImpl.

My question is : How do I set this property to not use Xalan ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Either set it statically from the command line when you execute your program, using the `-D` flag:

```
java -Dorg.apache.xalan.processor.TransformerFactoryImpl=com.xyz.YourFactory YourApp
```

Or dynamically from within your application, using [`System.setProperty()`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/lang/System.html#setProperty-java.lang.String-java.lang.String-):

```
System.setProperty("org.apache.xalan.processor.TransformerFactoryImpl",
        "com.xyz.YourFactory");
```

Note that you need to use the fully qualified class name of the factory class, and that the factory needs to be on your classpath for either of these to work.

Comment: Would you happen to know what the "platform default" is ?  From <https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/javax/xml/transform/TransformerFactory.html>

Comment: I found com.sun.org.apache.xalan.internal.xsltc.trax.TransformerFactoryImpl.

Comment: Thank you for your answer, I used System.setProperty() and System.clearProperty() to avoid impacting other parts of the project.

Comment: Unfortunately using System.setProperty() and System.clearProperty() does not avoid impacting other parts of the project. The effect may be short duration, but it affects anything that executes during that window. It's much better to use the version of newInstance() that accepts a classname for the factory. (Or just instantiate the factory directly, e.g. `factory = new net.sf.saxon.TransformerFactoryImpl()`.

Comment: This is not working for me. I need to create the instance from `javax.xml.transform.TransformerFactory`, but, it is creating the instance from `org.apache.xalan.processor.TransformerFactoryImpl`. Please help.

Comment: *javax.xml.transform.TransformerFactory* is part of the JAXP/TrAX API. It can not be instantiated directly (its constructor is private), and it does not itself create Transformers. Instead, when you call its static newInstance() method, it determines which implementation of *TransformerFactoryImpl* should be used and hands you an instance of that; you never run against *TransformerFactory* itself. Which implementation is used can be set with the system property as discussed above; the default depends on what's on your bootclasspath/classpath.

Answer (score 2):

Try to set it as a java argument `-Djavax.xml.transform.TransformerFactory=<factory class>`

You can also intantiate the desired factory directly in your program as `TransformerFactory tf = new SomeTransformerFactoryImpl();`